# Solving problem of sorting some numbers according to their number of divisors

Tags: python-3.x

how to program this question by just loop,functions and list in python?

"Write a program that reads 20 numbers from the input and at the end prints the number that has the most divisors with the number of divisors in the output. If several had this mode, print the largest of them."

Comment: what have you tried? are you having problems with some code?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: def num_with_most_divisors(input_list):

    def num_of_divisors(num):

        length = 0
        for i in range(1, num+1):
            if num % i == 0:
                length += 1
        return length

    y = sorted(input_list, key=lambda x: num_of_divisors(x), reverse=True)
    z = [len(num_of_divisors(k)) for k in y]

    final = []
    for j in y:
        l = len(num_of_divisors(j))

x = num_with_most_divisors([int(input()) for _ in range(4)])

Comment: this is my code.how can I continue and fix it?

Comment: please put the code in the question :)